# Integrate angular2 with nodejs

Tags: node.js, angular, express

[This is my file directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ocJ8N.png)

I am trying to integrate angular2 with nodejs. But index.js is not able to find the index.html file. Can someone please help me with it.(PS. I am a complete beginner).

[index.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J4ak1.png)

Below is the code for my index.html file.(This file is not able to load)

```
       <title>Hello World</title>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/es6-shim/0.33.3/es6-shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/systemjs/0.19.20/system-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/angular2-polyfills.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/system.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/tools/typescript.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/Rx.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/2.0.0-beta.6/angular2.dev.js"></script>
    <script>
      System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript',
        typescriptOptions: { emitDecoratorMetadata: true },
        packages: {'app': {defaultExtension: 'ts'}},
        map: { 'app': './app' }
      });
      System.import('app/hello_world_main')
            .then(null, console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
  </head>
<body>
   <my-app>Loading...</my-app>
</body>
```

Comment: Please add the code in the `index.js` in the question.

Comment: index.js is a screenshot

Comment: Your image of text [isn't very helpful](//meta.unix.stackexchange.com/q/4086).  It can't be read aloud or copied into an editor, and it doesn't index very well, meaning that other users with the same problem are less likely to find the answer here.  Please [edit] your post to incorporate the relevant text directly (preferably using copy+paste to avoid transcription errors).

Answer (score 1):

You should set the path for your static files like this:

```
app.use( express.static(__dirname + '/view' ) );
```

Source: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html